# Huge unusable font size in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts

As the title states, I've inadvertently set the font size to something gargantuan in Android studio and it's now totally unusable. At most I see the tops of a few letters once the program loads, so I can't even get back into the options to reduce the font size. Looking through the config files has given me no joy, so I am looking for some way of adjusting the settings from outside the program itself or deleting all user customised settings and starting again without completely deleting everything. I had tried to uninstall and reinstall, which worked for a short while then the font went back from normal to huge.

**Edit: I've managed to fix it (for now at least) by moving the .AndroidStudio1.2 file from my users folder and starting Android Studio again allowing it to reset.

Comment: I nearly got stuck myself by trying to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @mvai way to take one for the team

Comment: I hope I haven't started something awful - at least the solution from @iismathwizard works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to fix this is pretty easy actually.

Navigate to C:/Users/< your account >/.AndroidStudio/config/options/

Open ui.Inf.xml and change the FONT_SIZE property to an appropriate value (12 is default iirc)

Comment: Thank you, I just looked and I had "2212" instead. Go big or go home I guess!

Comment: Don't forget to pick this as the selected answer if this helped :)

Answer (score -1):

Outside of Android Studio, find your Project folder location, go into it and go into the `res>layout` folders, find your XML layout, open and edit the layout in notepad and you can change the size outside of Android Studio

Since you seem to be in quite the situation, go ahead and try these steps:

ctrl+alt+s

up arrow key (x7)

right arrow (x1)

down arrow (x1)

tab (x4)

backspace (x5)

type "12"

press enter

Comment: see "if all else fails" statement ^_^

Comment: I've tried that, but it's not the app that's the issue, it's studio itself. I initially tried changing it because the text in the menus etc was small and hard to read.

Comment: When I say go into the project directory I mean from outside of Android Studio (Windows File Explorer, etc). This was just to fix the text you accidentally made giant, unless you mean you tried changing the text size outside of AS

Comment: Yes, I've navigated to the file through the explorer and poked around in all the files I can open. The image I linked shows the screen when I open android studio, if I then try to close or do anything else the dialog box that the program generates also has huge text and is impossible to interact with. So it is the program settings I want to alter rather than the layout of an individual app.

Comment: So even after you changed the font size outside of Android Studio and saved the changes, when you open the project it hasn't changed? Interesting. .

Comment: @exlibris I didn't think that android studio could be made to be so terribly unusable..

Comment: Well there's nowhere to change the font size in the res>layout files, as they relate to the apps I've been working on and not the studio itself.

Comment: ahh, so to get things straight, you changed the font size in android studio itself, not the font size of something in a layout?

Comment: @iismathwizard The blame is mine and not android studio - I suspect that my finger slipped and the size 12 font I wanted turned into 120 or something

Comment: Okay, there is one more thing you can try - hopefully it will work out for you

Comment: That is assuming you went in and overrode the default fonts

Comment: Wow @HMiller, thanks for the step by step directions! Luckily I didn't have to resort to them in the end but I really appreciate the effort :)

Comment: No problem, always nice to have a last ditch effort :D