# Android Studio UI font is too big

Tags: android-studio

I'm using the Ubuntu 23.10 operating system. Recently, I updated my Android Studio to the latest version, which is version 2023.1 (Hedgehog). After the update, I encountered an issue where the font size in Android Studio became too large, despite setting it to size 13 in the preferences as shown in the attached image. I installed Android Studio using the Snap Store. Could you please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

I have attempted to reset the font but to no avail. Additionally, I have tried resolving it using the methods outlined in this link: [Huge unusable font size in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847730/huge-unusable-font-size-in-android-studio) , yet the font size remains large.

Images: [Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNNZB.png),
[Font Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYZF0.png)