# Change back to default font size in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fonts, resize, size

I accidentally set the font size to too large in Android Studio. I cannot use any function now including scrolling. I did not enable change font size by Ctrl+mouse wheel. How can I change back to default size?

[image: screen capture]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847730/huge-unusable-font-size-in-android-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30847730/huge-unusable-font-size-in-android-studio). I am using Android Studio Giraffe and there is no path called
C:/Users/< your account >/.AndroidStudio/config/options/. My path is

C:\Users\  \AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio2022.3\options

My case is that there is no font size set so just add `<option name="FONT_SIZE" value="12" />`.